# how to find if two rows of a column exist based on another column in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF,

```
   name  Id
0  ABC   i1
1  ABC   i2
2  PQR   i3
3  XYZ   i1
4  XYZ   i2
```

I want to find, `name`s that shares the same at least two `Id`s. I want to build a graph with weighted edges and weight is dependent on if two or more `Id`s share more than one name.

So, in this example there will be `i1` and `i2` having `ABC` and `XYZ` common.

I tried to achieve this by multiindexing int Pandas, where I created a new DF like following,

```
Id   name
i1   ABC
     ABC
i3   PQR
i2   XYZ
     XYZ
```

I am completely lost from here on. Thank you!

Expected output would be:

```
   Id1 Id2   count
0  i1  i2    2
1  i3  Null  Null
```

`count` will be the number of times there are `Id`s `i1` and `i2` having number of `name`s common.

**EDITED DF**

```
   name  Id
0  ABC   i1
1  ABC   i2
2  PQR   i3
3  XYZ   i1
4  QWE   i2
```

**##########**
Input DF, used for experimenting (`dups_df`)

```
   name  Id
0  ABC   i1
1  ABC   i2
2  QWE   i1
3  PQR   i3
4  XYZ   i2
```

**RESULTS**
Of this DF, 
`dups_df['UniqueID'] = dups_df['Id'].map(node2id)`

```
   name  Id  UniqueId
0  ABC   i1  1
1  ABC   i2  1
2  QWE   i1  1
3  PQR   i3  2
4  XYZ   i2  1
```

`dups_df=dups_df.groupby('UniqueID').agg({'name':'nunique', 'Id':'unique'})`

```
UniqueId  Name   Id
1         3      [i1,i2]
2         1      i3
```

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dups_df.pop('investors_uuids').tolist()).rename(columns= lambda x: "investors_uuids{}".format(x+1))
df1['count'] = dups_df['organization_name'].mask(dups_df['organization_name'].lt(2)).to_numpy()

**outputs**
  Id1  Id2  count
0 i1   i2   3
1 i3   None NaN
```

The last output DF is wrong, the count at index 0 should be NaN or 1 since in the new DF defined abouve called `dups_df` there is no other `name` common that is shared by `i1` and `i2` except `ABC` so the count should be 1 or NAN not 3!

**My Problem**
I have Ids and names columns, I want to build a network graph where I connect two Ids with an edge and the weight of the edge is defined if the two Ids(nodes) share more than one name.

Comment: what would your expected output look like?

Answer (score 4):

Use `networkx` with [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html):

```
import networkx as nx

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()


g.add_edges_from(df[['name','Id']].itertuples(index=False))

connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)

#create dict for common values
node2id = {}
for cid, component in enumerate(connected_components):
    for node in component:
        node2id[node] = cid + 1

df['UniqueID'] = df['Id'].map(node2id)
print (df)

0  ABC  i1         1
1  ABC  i2         1
2  PQR  i3         2
3  XYZ  i1         1
4  XYZ  i2         1
```

Then aggregate [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) ad create new DataFrame:

```
df = df.groupby('UniqueID').agg({'name':'nunique', 'Id':'unique'})
print (df)
          name        Id
UniqueID                
1            2  [i1, i2]
2            1      [i3]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Id').tolist()).rename(columns = lambda x: f'Id{x+1}')
df1['count'] = df['name'].mask(df['name'].lt(2)).to_numpy()
print (df1)
  Id1   Id2  count
0  i1    i2    2.0
1  i3  None    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, I am trying it now. Will get back to you soon. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I tried your solution. It works but it is not considering the column `name` when looking for common pairs of `Id`s. So, if we apply it on the original DF with the the edit I made in the question, the result is wrong the `count` is `3.0`. Which is not my desired output, I want the pair of Ids where each of them shares the same `name`s too like in Original DF.

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat - `but it is not considering the column name when looking for common pairs of Ids` - I use `g.add_edges_from(df[['name','Id']].itertuples(index=False))`, so it working also with `name, id` pairs. What is expected output from new data?

Comment: The output from the edited DF would be COunt `1` for `i1` and `i2`. Rest should have Ids `NaN`

Comment: THe thing is based on the first original DF, I want to build a graph using networkx, where `i1` and `i2` have an edge with weight 2, bc i1 and i2 both have lets say invested in `name` `ABC` and `XYZ` together. If there is no other `name` value where thex together invested then edge weight between them would be 1

Comment: yes. I do not care about the NaNs. I only want to find pairs of `Id`s that have common `name`s. Do you get what I mean? I am sorry if I am confusing you

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat - Not understand. If check my solution with `print (list(connected_components))` it is expected output from your old, new data? Or need something else?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question and tried to be more clearer this time. Please have a look at the part after `########`. Thank you for your time again. :)

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat - So `print (list(connected_components))` are correct? Because same groups menas same values of sets in `print (list(connected_components))`, sets are conected by same `id`, so `XYZ   i2  1` is connected by `ABC   i2  1` via `i2`. So now I am confused, it seems need somethinng else.

Comment: `[set([u' i2', u'XYZ', u' i1', u'ABC', u'QWE']),..]`. This is the print output. Which is not required, bc I want the second both `i1` and `i2` don't share same name, either `QWE` or `XYZ`. They both share different names. You get what I mean?